# Java 8 IntStream for an int range?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Is there a way to create an `IntStream` for a range of ints?

Like if I wanted to stream values 1 to 1000, I could invoke some `IntStream` static factory to stream that range?

```
IntStream.forRange(1, 1000).forEach(//do something...
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Never mind, I don't know why I missed it in the API documentation after reading it several times...

```
IntStream.range(1,1000)
```

Comment: and `rangeClosed` if you want upper bounds to be inclusive.

Comment: And add `.boxed()` if you want to map them to non-integers: `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).boxed().map(i -> new User("username " + i)).collect(toImmutableList())`

Comment: Or `.mapToObj()`: `IntStream.rangeClosed(1,10).mapToObj(i -> new User("username " + i)).toList();`