# How to generate auto int array from 0 to 99

Tags: java, arrays, automation, integer

there is any way to generate auto int array from 0 to 99

**Example:**

```
int [] nums = new int[99];
```

i want it like this:

```
int [] Nums = new int[] {0,1,2,3,4... ,99};
```

Thanks in advance <3 <3.

Comment: Stick to Java naming conventions, so it should be `nums` (lowercase 'n') ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 int [] nums = new int[99];
 for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
     nums[i] = i;
```

Other ways if you are using Java 8:

- First technique

  `int[] nums = IntStream.range(0, 99).toArray();`
- Second technique

  `int[] nums = new int[99];
  Arrays.setAll(nums, i -> i + 1);`

Comment: You mean `i<99` or `i < Nums.length`, not `i< =99`

Comment: Wrong, java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and `< =` not compile : `<=`

Comment: @AbdelilahElghazal if it helped accept the answer using green tick. Happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

Combining [Java 8 IntStream for an int range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313726/java-8-intstream-for-an-int-range) and [How to Convert a Java 8 Stream to an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079003/how-to-convert-a-java-8-stream-to-an-array):

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 99).toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Comment: An `Integer` array is not an `int` array.

Comment: @khelwood I didn't test, but I thought that's why there is `toArray`...

Comment: The OP asked for an `int` array, not an `Integer` array. `toArray(Integer[]::new)` will not even compile. It should be just `toArray()`. See [`IntStream.toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#toArray--)

Comment: Now I tested and You are correct. But `Integer::new` is ok in Java 8?

Comment: It seems it might work somewhere, but `Integer[] arr = Integer[]::new;` shows compilation error "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface".

Comment: @Betlista Integer[]::new is equivalent to i -> new Integer[i]. It's type is IntFunction<Integer[]>, so you can't assign it to an Integer[].