# StackOverflowError when implementing Iterator

Tags: java, recursion

I am supposed to create a simulation that does what pythons xrange does which is pick a start number, stop number, and step number in java. I am having trouble passing my constructor numbers to the Range class as it gives me an Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError. Everytime I step thru the program The Range constructor changes back to "Rane@365", I'm not sure what It means but my numbers I provide are gone.

```
 package com.company;

 public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (Integer num: new Range(1,10,2)) {
        System.out.println(num++);
    }

}

}
```

This is my Range class that uses interfaces Iterator and interface Iterable

```
package com.company;

 import java.util.Iterator;

public class Range implements Iterable<Integer>, Iterator<Integer> {

public Range(int start, int stop, int step){

    start = start;
    stop = stop;
    step = step;
}


public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {

    return this;
}


public boolean hasNext() {
    if (!this.hasNext()) {
        return true;
    } else
    return false;
}


public Integer next() {
    if (!hasNext()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No next");
    }
    return null;
}

public void remove() {

}
```

}

The stuff I have read uses ArrayLists, and I havent found anything on constructors and using loops for the Iterator and Iterable interfaces. I know the hasNext, next, remove are built in methods, where would the loop be? In the Main class or in one of the built in classes?

Comment: Why does it make sense for `Range` to be both `Iterable` and an `Iterator` simultaneously?

Comment: Of course you get a stack overflow. Your `hasNext()` method calls itself and tries to return the opposite of its own return value. How is that supposed to work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313726/java-8-intstream-for-an-int-range

Comment: For help on exceptions, it would be nice to post a few lines of the exception Trace.

Comment: For a better solution, consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358827/intstream-iterate-in-steps

Comment: I don't know I've never worked with either iterable and iterator this is just the template I was given.

Answer (score 0):

There is an infinite recursion here:

```
public boolean hasNext() {
    if (!this.hasNext()) {
      ...
```

This method calls itself every time, increasing the stack, until you get the StackOverflowException.